# Source reordering in Bourbon Neat

Tags: css, responsive-design, bourbon, neat

i am new to Neat. I am unable to figure out how to reorder the columns in bourbon neat grid. 
can someone give me some tip please.
thanks.
i read the documentation but i didn't understand anything useful for ordering.
thanks.

Comment: How do you want the columns ordered? What are you looking for?

Comment: I found the answer to your question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24868817/re-ordering-columns-with-thoughtbot-bourbon-neat).